# Permission difference between root root and www-data root

Tags: 14.04, permissions, filesystem, root, groups

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root 1502 May 14 23:06 file1.css
-rw------- 1 www-data root  894 Mar 28 01:10 file2.html
```

What is the permission difference between these two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux and Unix, everything is a file. Directories are files, files are files and devices are files. Devices are usually referred to as a node; however, they are still files. All of the files on a system have permissions that allow or prevent others from viewing, modifying or executing.

In first one

```
 -rw-r--r--
```

the permissions are as follows for user, group and others

```
owner = Read & Write (rw-)
group = Read (r--)
other = Read (r--)
```

while in second one

```
-rw-------
```

only user have read, write permission,i.e

```
owner = Read & Write (rw-)
group = None (---)
other = None (---)
```

For more details read [File Permissions Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Answer (score 1):

The first file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root 1502 May 14 23:06 file1.css
```

This file `root root` is owned by the user `root` which as you can see is specified by being in the file owner column of the listing.  The second reference to `root` is in the 4th column of the listing.  That is the column that is showing the group owner of the file.  The group owner is root.

The second file:

```
-rw------- 1 www-data root  894 Mar 28 01:10 file2.html
```

As specified by what's shown in the 3rd column, this file is owned by the username `www-data`.  as you can see, the group owner of the second file is `root`.

You have usernames (user id) and group names (group id) for who owns files in Unix/Linux.  The names of the user and group can be the same, or they can be different.  Using the `Long Listing` of `ls` (`ls -l`), you can see this type of detail about the file.

#### Quick answer

In short, the difference is the specific `userid owner` and `group id owner`.  They are different in the two files.

---

Below is more details about the listing.  A significant characteristic of the files is specified in column one of the listing.  It is showing the type of permission given to the file, such as read, write, and execution.

#### Column explanation

1. Permissions
2. Number of links
3. User
4. Group
5. Size
6. Month Modified
7. Date Modified
8. Time Modified
9. File or Directory Name